# Creating zipped file of many pdfs automatically

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am trying to zip a series of pdf files automatically when a page loads. The files are based on a query. I can't seem to figure out the error. All of the pdfs are kept in the agreements folder and I want the zip file to just download on the viewer's computer. The error code that I get is:

agreements/Acadience_Cambridge_Post_1.pdfagreements/DoTheMath_Cambridge.pdfagreements/Edulog_Cambridge.pdfagreements/DESSA_Cambridge.pdfagreements/FuelEducation_Cambridge_signed.pdfagreements/LegendsofLearning_Dedham.pdfagreements/workforce19-22.pdfagreements/Ellevation_Dedham_Posting.pdfagreements/Yabla_Cambridge.pdfagreements/Breakthrough-2020.pdfagreements/Cedar-Labs-DPA.pdfagreements/Tutoring Plus.pdfagreements/Elefante Letrado_Brockton - post.pdfagreements/CollegeBoard_Cambridge_post_1.pdfagreements/LanguageConnections_post.pdfagreements/Flat_Westford - post.pdfagreements/Albert.io_Cambridge_post.pdfagreements/Starfall_Walpole.pdfagreements/Tynker_Milton - post_1.pdfagreements/WeVideo_CambridgeTEC_1.pdfagreements/Checkology_Dedham.pdfagreements/BabylonHouse _Cambridge_signed_4.pdfagreements/FreeMath_Westwood_Post.pdf
Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied in /var/www/html/extract_dpas2.php on line 36
Could not find Zip file to download

Here is the code I have:

```html
<?php require_once('Connections/sdpc_i.php'); ?>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE districtID = 457 and statusID=1 and signed_agreement_file != 'NULL'";
if ($result=mysqli_query($sdpc_i,$sql))
{    
    // $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
    //define array for storing files
    $file = array(); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
        //give file name with extension    
        $name ="agreements/".$row['signed_agreement_file'];
        //store file name in array
        $file[] = $name;
        // store file in one folder named 'files'
        file_put_contents($name,$row["signed_agreement_file"]);

    }
    $zipname = "file.zip";
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
$zip->open($zip_name,  ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($file as $f) {
  echo $path = "".$f;
  if(file_exists($path)){
  $zip->addFromString(basename($path),  file_get_contents($path));  
  }
  else{
   echo"file does not exist";
  }
}
$zip->close();
    //check zip file create or not and download it
    if (file_exists($zipname)) {
       header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($zipname).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($zipname);
        exit;
    } else {
        exit("Could not find Zip file to download");
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: `Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied in /var/www/html/extract_dpas2.php on line 36` means that this is not a code related issue. What server are you running on? If it's Linux, make sure the web server user has the right permission to access the folder that contains your PDFs.

Comment: So, the permissions on the folder containing the pdfs has write abilities. Is the temporary file being created in a different spot? That is the part that I can't tell. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I solved the permissions error but now, I am getting this error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ....

Comment: Also, the file downloads but, none of the pdfs can be opened. They are all corrupt. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `addFile` instead of `addFromString`.